# How to change filename in PostgreSQL 10

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to change filename in PostgreSQL 10

```
filename         |    
:----------------------------- |
abc.zip;efg.zip     |
```

It's like here

```
filename         |    
:------------------------------ |
filename(1).zip;filename(2).zip |
```

Comment: `REPLACE(filename, 'abc.zip', 'filename(1).zip')` - storing multiple values as text is bad practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . .  You should fix your data model so you are not storing lists in a string.  But you can do what you want by splitting the filename and then reconstructing the new names:

```
select *
from (values ('abc.zip;efg.zip')) x(filenames) cross join lateral
     (select string_agg('filename(' || n || ').' || split_part(filename, '.', 2), ';') as newnames
      from unnest(string_to_array(x.filenames, ';')) with ordinality s(filename, n)
     ) s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6fa6b8b8943fbba30dffb4375ebcfcdc) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I actually could not think of an easy way to do the replacement on the CSV string of filenames itself.  But it is bad practice to store CSV anyway, and your table should instead look something like this:

```
id | filename
1  | abc.zip
1  | efg.zip
2  | blah.txt
2  | stuff.jpg
```

Given this, we can use the following select query to enumerate the files as you want:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    filename,
    'filename(' ||
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY filename))::text ||
    ')' ||
    REGEXP_REPLACE(filename, '^[^.]+', '') AS filename_out
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo